# Is there a way to determine whether onCreate() has just been called prior to onResume()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Is there a way to determine whether onCreate() has just been called prior to onResume().

I wan't to do stuff in onCreate() for view initialization etc, but I don't want to do them again in onResume(), and I'd still like the stuff to be done each time I resume...

Is there a way to determine whether the application has just been created prior to entering the current onResume()?

Comment: Why don't you just do them **always** in onResume and remove them from onCreate?

Comment: Why not just put the stuff you want to be in `onResume()` only in `onResume()`? It's called with `onCreate()`.

Comment: How about simply initializing a counter in `onCreate` that counts how many times `onResume` has been called? Set the counter to 0 during each call to `onCreate`. In `onResume`, you check (and subsequently increment) the counter. If it is 0, `onCreate` has just been called, if it is non-zero, the activity has been resumed (no `onCreate` call).

Comment: It's not my code, and some stuff has to be initialized in onCreate() for some reason, painting views or whatever. But then I want the stuff to also be run in onResume().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in system call that will tell you whether or not `onResume()` is being called because the activity was simply paused, or whether it's being called because the activity was entirely re-created. So you will have to track it yourself.

It's relatively easy to set a `boolean` in `onCreate()` and then check it in `onResume()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean didCreate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        this.didCreate = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ...

        if (didCreate) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }

        this.didCreate = false;
    }
}
```